# how to escape the ' in ssh?

Tags: bash

I need to escape the ' in this command for ssh exec

```
grep IPADDR /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 |awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

How do I escape that?

I currentl y have this which does not work

```
ssh host 'grep IPADDR /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 |awk -F= '{print $2}''
```

nor does this

```
ssh host 'grep IPADDR /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 |awk -F= \'{print $2}\''
```

thanks,
Dean

Comment: You cannot escape single quotes within a single quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

never mind, I just found this awesome snippet which is way cool so I don't need to keep asking how to escape this or that...

```
ssh user@serverB <<\EOF
your sql query....
.....
.....
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to do any substitution (parameter, command, etc) inside the string, you can use `$'...'` quoting:

```
ssh user@serverB $'grep str file | awk \'{print $2}\''
```

As a side note, you can usually replace `grep`/`awk` pipelines with a single call to `awk`:

```
ssh user@serverB $'awk \'/str/ {print $2}\' file'
```

Comment: need to escape the `$` if you use double quotes around the awk body

Comment: Right; that double-quote is left over from a different approach I was going to try, though. Removing it entirely to make a correct call to `awk` inside `$'...'`.